# Spring Boot / MVC - How to customize handling of return types for controller methods?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Spring Boot 2.3

I would like to return Kotlin's Result type from a Spring Boot controller method. This type can either be an exception or a success. If it is an exception, I would like to extract this and allow it to flow to the normal ExceptionHandler. If it is a success, then I want to extract this and allow it to flow out as if it had been returned from the controller method.

I am having trouble finding information on how to add additional controller result type handlers in Spring Boot. Any help that can be provided toward this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried using `ResponseEntity` wrapper class in spring boot? Using this you can output two different response from the controller

Comment: @Avinash I am aware pf the ResponseEntity, but I need to know how to map custom return types.

Comment: Is it ok if I give an example in Java?